# (Python Derived Classes) Not getting the correct output

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance

This is my desired output:

```
Name: Smith, Age: 20, ID: 9999
```

Here is my code so far

```
class PersonData:
def __init__(self):
    self.last_name = ''
    self.age_years = 0

def set_name(self, user_name):
    self.last_name  = user_name

def set_age(self, num_years):
    self.age_years = num_years

# Other parts omitted

def print_all(self):
    output_str = 'Name: ' + self.last_name + ', Age: ' + str(self.age_years)
    return output_str


class StudentData(PersonData):
def __init__(self):
    PersonData.__init__(self)  # Call base class constructor
    self.id_num = 0

def set_id(self, student_id):
    self.id_num = student_id

def get_id(self):
    return self.id_num


course_student = StudentData()

course_student = StudentData()
course_student.get_id(9999)
course_student.set_age(20)
course_student.set_name("Smith")

print('%s, ID: %s' % (course_student.print_all(), course_student.get_id()))
```

At the moment, it isn't running. I would really appreciate it if someone could help out. It is returning a type error for line 34, and I am not sure how to correct it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the full error message.  One thing I noticed is you're calling `get_id` where you should be calling `set_id`

Comment: Including the text of the type error would help, but I imagine it's happening because you called `get_id(9999)` instead of `set_id(9999)`.

Comment: You're passing `9999` into get_id, but get_id doesnt take any arguments

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking the parent init wrongly there...

Here's how you're supposed to do it:

```
class PersonData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_name = ''
        self.age_years = 0

    def set_name(self, user_name):
        self.last_name  = user_name

    def set_age(self, num_years):
        self.age_years = num_years

    # Other parts omitted

    def print_all(self):
        output_str = 'Name: ' + self.last_name + ', Age: ' + str(self.age_years)
        return output_str


class StudentData(PersonData):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # Call base class constructor
        self.id_num = 0

    def set_id(self, student_id):
        self.id_num = student_id

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id_num


course_student = StudentData()

course_student = StudentData()
course_student.set_id(9999)
course_student.set_age(20)
course_student.set_name("Smith")

print('%s, ID: %s' % (course_student.print_all(), course_student.get_id()))
```

I also noticed that in the execution, you were calling `course_student.get_id(9999)` but I think you meant `course_student.set_id(9999)`

Comment: Thanks for explaining that! It was giving me trouble for a while

Comment: Don't forget to mark the response as the answer so others can learn from it too

Answer (score 0):

here's the correct way to pass all test using ZyBooks

```
class PersonData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_name = ''
        self.age_years = 0

    def set_name(self, user_name):
        self.last_name  = user_name

    def set_age(self, num_years):
        self.age_years = num_years

    # Other parts omitted

    def print_all(self):
        output_str = 'Name: ' + self.last_name + ', Age: ' + 
        str(self.age_years)
        return output_str


class StudentData(PersonData):
    def __init__(self):
        PersonData.__init__(self)  # Call base class constructor
        self.id_num = 0

    def set_id(self, student_id):
        self.id_num = student_id
        
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id_num


course_student = StudentData()
course_student.set_name('Smith')
course_student.set_age(20)
course_student.set_id(9999)

print('{}, ID: {}'.format(course_student.print_all(), 
course_student.get_id()))
```

be sure you dont have the line course_student = StudentData( ) coded twice in your code because then your instructor will know that you copied it and pasted it from another website.

Comment: This code is full of `IndentationError`s. Please [edit] it and fix them.